# One question about topology.

Tags: general-topology

Why is the set $ A=\{ (x ,x^{-1}):0<x\leqslant 1\}$ is closed in $\Bbb R^2$ but is not bounded?
Why is the set $ S=\{(x,\sin(x^{-1})) :0<x\leqslant 1\}$ is bounded in $\Bbb  R^2$ but is not closed?

I am just a beginner in topology, so I hope someone can answer it in detail. Thanks.

Comment: These are two questions.

Comment: Do you mean $(x, \frac{1}{x})$ for the first?

Comment: Your notation is incorrect: I’m quite sure that you mean $\left\langle x,\frac1x\right\rangle$ in the first set and $\left\langle x,\sin\frac1x\right\rangle$ in the second.

Comment: These are just graphs of 1/x and sin(1/x) respectively.

Comment: Your notation is non-standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, you mean $A=\{(x,1/x)\,\mid\,0<x\le1\}$ and $S=\{(x,\sin(1/x))\,\mid\,0<x\le 1\}$/

Well, $A$ is not bounded because $1/x$ can be arbitrary big as $x$ is close to $0$, so actually it is not bounded from upside. $S$ is bounded because $\sin($anything$)$ is always between $-1$ and $1$, and now the first coordinate $x$ is also bounded. So, $S$ is contained in a rectangle, hence it is also contained in a disc, so it is bounded.

$A$ is closed because it contains all limit points. If $x_n$ is a sequence in $(0,1]$, and $x_n\to x$ for some $x\in (0,1]$ then we have $1/x_n\to 1/x$, so the sequence $(x_n,1/x_n)$ in $\Bbb R^2$ converges to $(x,1/x)$.

$S$ is not closed, because there are limit points at $x=0$ which are not contained in $S$, e.g. if we take $x_n:=\displaystyle\frac1{2n\pi+\pi/2}$, then $(x_n,\sin(1/x_n))\to (0,1)$ which is $\notin S$.

Answer (score 0):

For the first,  $(\frac{1}{n},n) \in A$ for all $n$, and $\|(\frac{1}{n},n)\| \ge n$, hence $A$ is unbounded. 
You can write $A$ as $A= \{(x,y) | y \ge 1, xy=1 \} = (\mathbb{R} \times [1,\infty)) \cap f^{-1}(\{1\})$, where $f(x,y) = xy$ ($f$ is continuous) and both of these sets are closed.

For the second, it is clear that if $(x,y) \in S$, then $|x| \le 1, |y| \le 1$, hence $S$ is bounded. If we take $x_n = \frac{1}{n \pi}$, then $(x_n,\sin \frac{1}{x_n}) = (\frac{1}{n \pi}, 0) \in S$ for all $n$, but $(0,0) \notin S$. Hence $S$ is not closed.